# How to reset a millis() variable back to zero

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

So the Code is:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int sec = 0;
int mts = 0;
int hrs = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  sec = millis() / 1000;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("Seconds:");
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print(sec);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
  lcd.print("Mnt:");
  if (sec >= 59) {
    sec = 0;
    mts = mts + 1;
    lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
    lcd.print(mts);
  } else {
    lcd.setCursor(13,1);
    lcd.print(mts);
  }
  delay(1000)
}
```

The problem is i can't reset the `sec` variable to zero,

I have tried many ways but all of them failed.

Is there a way to make it start counting back to start

Comment: Find out how to use timer interrupts or even better use a RTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because the `millis` is updating the `sec` variable.

After the `sec` reaches the `59` value, your `if` statement changes the `sec` to `0`. However the `millis` will again put the latest time value i.e. `60` and `lcd.print(sec)` will print it. And the cycles continues, without ever resetting the `sec` value because `millis` is updating it.

One more thing, don't use `delay(1000)` to stop the controller for `1` second, You need make use of the sole purpose of the `millis` i.e. to avoid `delays`.

Here is your solution:

```c
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13);
long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long sec = 0;
unsigned long mts = 0;
unsigned long hrs = 0;

void setup() {
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if(currentMillis - previousMillis > 1000) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;   
        sec +=1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Seconds:");
        lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
        lcd.print(sec);
        lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
        lcd.print("Mnt:");
        if (sec >= 59) {
            sec = 0;
            mts +=1;
        }
        lcd.setCursor(11,1);
        lcd.print(mts);
        }  
    }
}
```